# Cannot connect both PC and Laptop over LAN with Router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, internet

```
             _
  ROUTER     ||
_____________||
|    D-Link   |
|             |
| L1 L2 L3 L4 |
---|-----|--|--
   |     |  |
   |     |  |____________ < ISP 
   |     |                  (Static IP: 172 series)
   |     |_______
  [PC]          |
192.168.1.2     |
                |
          [Lenovo E431]
           192.168.1.3
```

I have an ADSL Wi-Fi Modem/Router which I am using to configure a LAN
My ISP provides me a Static IP-based connection via an RJ-45 cable. Once connected, I am presented with a landing page where I put my username/pwd, and it allows me to access the internet. I have configured my Router in EoA mode using the following architecture.
Basically, I am not using the DSL port Or the Wireless part as of now (Long story). Out of my 3 LAN connections, 1 is incoming (L4) and 2 are outgoing (L1, L3).
Outgoing cables are connected to:

1. PC (L1)
2. Lenovo E431 laptop (L2/L3)

My router is configured with a DHCP server which assigns IPs 192.168.2 through 10. All the static IP config is in my router, and none in the connected PC/Laptop.

#### Issue:

While the PC connection is working fine (with TCP/IP settings set to automatic configuration), the same configuration is not working on the Lenovo E431 laptop.
The DHCP server is able to assign IPs fine as shown above, but the internet connectivity is not working in E431. Surprisingly I am able to access the landing page from both the PC and laptop and authenticate there. Its just the next step (say, google.com) which is not working from the laptop.

#### I have tried so far:

- Reinstalling the driver for the Ethernet Card in E431
- Putting the DNS server settings in the E431 (Still assigning Dynamic IPs)
- Plugging the ISP cable directly into E431 (PC now offline) and configuring TCP/IP: Still not working, and network symbol constantly connecting and disconnecting on the laptop

#### Bottomline:

## PLEASE HELP!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue eventually got solved. The trick was a mere fluke: Hard-reset the router to factory settings and reconfigure using exactly the steps used previously to configure it. It involved:

- Create new Ethernet interface with default settings
- Use the 4th LAN port as the WAN replacement (Also default)
- Choose 'IP over Ethernet' as connection mode
- Enable NAT (Network Address Translation)
- Use the static IP and Gateway details provided by my ISP in the LAN settings
- Set 'Primary Uplink' to 'Ethernet' under 3G settings
- Save and Reboot Router

Not sure why it had stopped working meanwhile, must be one of the settings listed above. Worked like a charm after reset, and now all LAN/WLAN connections are working in true EoA mode. I can authenticate on any device and have the connection enabled in other  ones. This link helped me re-configure my **D-Link DSL-2750U** router:
http://broadbandforum.co/threads/75482/